# Creating MBean in Java

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I am trying to make a class implement an MBean Interface so I can interrogate the properties at runtime. The class I am trying to interrogate is as follows

```
public class ProfileCache implements ProfileCacheInterfaceMBean{

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProfileCache.class);
    private ConcurrentMap<String, Profile> cache;


    public ProfileCache(ConcurrentMap<String, Profile> cache){
        this.cache = cache;     
    }

    /**
     * Update the cache entry for a given user id
     * @param userid the user id to update for 
     * @param profile the new profile to store
     * @return true if the cache update
     */
    public boolean updateCache(String userid, Profile profile) {
        if (cache == null || cache.size() == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to update the cache");
        }
        if (cache.containsKey(userid)) {
            if (profile != null) {
                cache.put(userid, profile);
                logger.info("Updated the cache for user: "
                            + userid + "  profile: " + profile);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ConcurrentMap<String, Profile> getCache() {
        if(cache == null){
            cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Profile>();
        }
        return cache;
    }


}
```

The interface looks like this

```
import com.vimba.profile.Profile;

public interface ProfileCacheInterfaceMBean {

    ConcurrentMap<String, Profile> getCache();

}
```

And i start the MBean like this

```
        cacheImpl = new ProfileCache(factory.createCacheFromDB());
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName profileCache = new ObjectName("org.javalobby.tnt.jmx:type=ProfileCacheInterfaceMBean");  
        mbs.registerMBean(cacheImpl, profileCache);
```

However i keep getting the below exception and I am not sure what I need to change

```
javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: MBean class com.vimba.cache.ProfileCache does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class com.vimba.cache.ProfileCache is not a JMX compliant Standard MBean) nor the MXBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: com.vimba.cache.ProfileCache: Class com.vimba.cache.ProfileCache is not a JMX compliant MXBean)
```

I think potentially it's because it returns a Map?

Comment: Thanks for such a helpful comment, if i understood what was meant i would not have posted here. No doubt your sarcasm should help get you a few more points - good work

Comment: That was a genuine question. Anyway, which part of the exception do you not understand? To start, with "does not implement" --> Indicates that your class needs to implement the interface.

Comment: This is the source of my confusion as the tutorial i followed did not implement this interface - maybe i should just go and rtfm

Comment: Renaming the Managed Bean class name to end as "YourClasssNameMXBean" worked for me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Having just encountered this exception and looked at the current answers as well as https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/javax_management_standardmbean_when_and I thought it might help to emphasize and clarify the following already elucidated to:

1. The NotCompliantMBeanException is caused, among other things, by failing to follow this convention 'ConcreteClassName' implements 'ConcreteClassNameMBean'
2. I resolved this by updating the original name of my mbean interface from 'OrignalNameMBean' to 'OriginalNameMXBean' allowing the mbean to be registered without following the convention
3. Another solution would be to follow the convention.

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Comment: But solution is still valid :)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue ("does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions") and this article helped me to resolve the problem (see Using StandardMBean section: https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/javax_management_standardmbean_when_and).

I have to explicitly construct a

```
StandardMBean mbean = new StandardMBean(mBeanImpl, MBeanInterface.class);
```

then register the mbean:

```
mbServer.registerMBean(mbean, mBeanName);
```

It works.

When I register the mBeanImpl with the mbServer, I got the above exception.

Comment: best answer for me

Answer (score 8):

The implementing mbean class can declare as many methods as it likes that are not defined in mbeans interface... There is no requirement that the implementing class can/must **only** implement the interface methods.

In many of the cases this problem is caused because the **mbean interface and implementation class are not in the same package**!

Comment: This indeed was the case, thank you! Moving the interface into the same package as the implementation, resolved the error for me.

Comment: I ran into the same issue because interface and implementation were in different artifacts of the same ear, and there was a refactor that did not account for the package structure in the api artifact. After resolving the package structure in the implementation artifact to be the same then the api artifact, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

You can change interface name from SomethingMBean to SomethingM**X**Bean,such as HelloMBean to HelloMXBean,from jdk's source code i saw this:

```
public static boolean isMXBeanInterface(Class<?> interfaceClass) {
    if (!interfaceClass.isInterface())
        return false;
    if (!Modifier.isPublic(interfaceClass.getModifiers()) &&
        !Introspector.ALLOW_NONPUBLIC_MBEAN) {
        return false;
    }
    MXBean a = interfaceClass.getAnnotation(MXBean.class);
    if (a != null)
        return a.value();
    return interfaceClass.getName().endsWith("MXBean");
}
```

if not endsWith "MXBean",it will return false,then cause throw IllegalArgumentException

jdk version:1.8.0_25

class is "JMX",line 376

Answer (score 2):

Just change interface suffix from 'MBean' to 'MXBean'.
This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your implementation class name from ProfileCache  to ProfileCacheInterface. It should work now. Moreover your implementation class can have any number of its own methods and those methods needs not to be mentioned in the MBean interface.

JMX's standard mbean naming convention is like this

```
    public interface SomeBeanNameMBean{
    ...
    }

    public class SomeBeanName implements SomeBeanNameMBean{
    ...
    //implements all the methods of SomeBeanNameMBean
    ...
    //implement other class's own methods if needed
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem like 'Exception in thread "main" javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException', in my case I kept MBean interface and implementation classes in differnet package. To resolve the issue, I moved both MBean interface and the implementation class to same package.

Answer (score 0):

In the all the examples I've seen for MBean implementations, I've never seen a class define a method that was not defined in the interface. E.g., ProfileCache has method updateCache, but ProfileCacheInterfaceMBean does not. Try removing the updateCache method from ProfileCache and see if it will work.

Comment: both have the method getCache?

Comment: Just try commenting out method updateCache in ProfileCache and see if that exception is still thrown.

Comment: why would that make any difference though?!

Comment: Because it appears an MBean implementation requires that only the interface methods are implemented; no additional methods should be implemented in the ProfileCache. At this point, if you post another comment before trying to comment out updateCache, YOU'RE trolling for rep.

Comment: the answer below is the correct one. It is not a problem for adding additional methods in the MBean implementation